# Copying style from querySelector

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm trying to copy a style from the `.current_page_item` to different elements.

I am using WordPress and am not sure of another way to do this dynamically.

Essentially, I am using one style to color the `.current_page_item` (which changes colors depending on which page), and that is modifying the header color, and the post and content background colors.

The way I have thought up to do this is via JavaScript.

Here is my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var page_color = document.querySelector('li.current_page_item').style.backgroundColor;

    document.querySelector('div.blog-post p').style.backgroundColor = page_color;
    document.querySelector('h2.blog-post-title').style.backgroundColor = page_color;
}
```

It doesn't seem to be reading the backgroundColor from `.current_page_item`, but I am able to set it if I use the same method.

Here is the page: http://whatloop.com/wpTheme/

Thanks!

Comment: not sure why you're not just using classes instead then

Comment: I haven't found a way to add or change classes on a WordPress post with `<?php the_content(); ?>`, if I were to be able to.. would it allow me to add a class with a color that would change depending on the page?

Comment: what does `console.log(page_color);` output

Comment: That is blank as well @JaromandaX

Comment: so, the element `li.current_page_item` has no inline style that sets the background color ... try using `getComputedStyle` in that case

Comment: That worked @JaromandaX! Do you want to add that as an answer to accept it?